# MySQL bulk insert data error handling

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, batch-processing, bulkinsert

My C# application batch-updates data in a MySQL database. The SQL query is in the form of `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`.

When an error in one row fails, the entire SQL query fails. How can I handle any error gracefully (eg. print out the error for that row) and then move on to the next row to update?

Comment: Use `INSERT IGNORE` and it will still update the remainder.